# Relate two paged sharepoint List as a parent-child

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i have two lists named "Categories" and "Products".I paged "Categories" List in a dataview(1 object per page). At the bottom of this dataview, i paged "Products" List in a different dataview.

What i want is if i change category by clicking paging button(it navigates second category), products should be filtered by category that i changed.

Shortly,i want to relate two paged list as parent-child.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use WebPart Connections to achive this, Following links would help you to get started on WebPart Connections in DataView WebPart page.

[Using Filters with DataView WebPart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-data-view-web-part-HA010250997.aspx)

[Multiple Filters with DataView WebPart](http://sharepointxperiments.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/multiple-filters-on-a-data-view-webpart/)